JavaFX: Squished Stage icon in Windows Task Manager
I'm working on a project in JavaFX 21 and adding a stage icon using stage.getIcons.
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/linux/32.png")));
This works fine; the image is displayed both in the top left of the window, as well as in Task Manager - both in the Linux and Windows (11) builds of my program.
What isn't working is that inside Windows Task Manager, and only there, the icon is squished. It looks fine in the task manager of my Xubuntu VM which I program on.
This is my icon (the 256x256px version for better visibility).
And this is what I see in Task Manager. For this image, I was using the 32x32px version of the icon with a thicker yellow line, but the icon is still circular.
I'm also using JavaPackager to package my code as an executable Windows version, and I use a Windows .ico file for all the icon usages which aren't the window bar top left icon or the Task Manager process icon, and that works perfectly fine. However, I don't think this should be related as the problematic icon is added via JavaFX inside the code itself.
Is there anything specific going on between JavaFX and the Windows Task Manager causing this weird squishing?
What I tried so far:

Use different icon image sizes (16, 32, 64, 256px)
Add multiple images of different sizes in the stage.getIcons() call
Instead of the icon version I posted with a little whitespace on the sides, I made a second version cut to size
Refresh Windows Explorer to reload the icon cache (?)

All without any effect.

This could be some kind of bug, but I would use three different size images like this

I did rescaling with boolean proportional set to true.
See preserveRatio.
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(IMG));
Image img1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(IMG), 16, 16, true, true);
Image img2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(IMG), 24, 24, true, true);
stage.getIcons().addAll(img, img1, img2);

Not sure whether your problem is indeed one unproportional scaling on the file side.

Didn't think to try that - but unfortunately, I just tried it and it seems to have no effect. The window top bar icon stays correct, and the Win11 Task Manager icon stays squished (even after reloading Explorer).

I had the hope that the one icon picked of the icons still needed to be resized.  You can test what icon is picked (16x16?) by clearly different icon (color?).. Pervers would be needing to create a widened 24x16 icon.
